# Add custom Component in mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have create a mat-tab that I reuse a lot in my different tab-groups.
Since I do not repeat code, I created a component `mat-tab-foo`.
It contains the following HTML:

```
 <mat-tab label="Foo">
   <p>Bar</p>
 </mat-tab>
```

I tried using it in my `mat-tab-group` like so:

```
 <mat-tab-group>
   <mat-tab-foo></mat-tab-foo>
 </mat-tab-group>
```

But the tab is never rendered, does anyone know how to render `mat-tab-foo` inside the `mat-tab-group`?

A Stackblitz example can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dppfhx).

Comment: Can you create Stackblitz?

Comment: @Tushar I've created a stackblitz example

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13380 there is existing issue for this

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I'm seeing the same problem, and not seeing any solutions anywhere.

Comment: @KyleAnderson Never had an answer and I think I give up on the idea. Not sure how we solved/worked around it tough.

Answer (score 1):

I think that post can help you, look the second answer too:

[Angular Material Tabs not working with wrapper component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840703/angular-material-tabs-not-working-with-wrapper-component)

Basically, you have to wrapper the mat-tab-group in another component and add the tabs in the .ts. It worked for me